# R: Is there a way to Vlookup with partial match between two dataframes columns

Tags: r, vlookup, partial-matches

I have 2 dataframes (df1 & df2)

df 1:

[image]

df 2 :

[image]

Required Output:

df3

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and where have you failed? Have you devised an algorithm to get this done (using pen and paper)?

Comment: The regex-join from the fuzzyjoin-package is ideal doe this.

Comment: My bad, I missed to put my try. Below is the code, I tried. But no luck... library(tidyverse)
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate( df2= lapply(almname, function(x){df2 %>% filter(grepl(x, almname))})
  ) %>%
unnest(df2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the pictures, you should try to put the data in reproducible format. Also, try to show some work but I can understand that you may not know where to even begin. But at least show what you have attempted whether it works or not.

Will something like this work?

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(almId = c(12347, 123455, 112625, 112621), almname = c("1001 battery down", "2077 Power issue", "7166 DG fault", "2122 cable cut"))

df2 <- data.frame(almname = c("battery down", "Power issue", "DG fault", "Circuit break"))

k <- paste0(df2$almname, collapse = "|")
df1 %>% mutate(Stat = stringr::str_detect(.$almname, k))

df3 <- df1 %>% mutate(Stat = stringr::str_detect(.$almname, k))

   almId           almname  Stat
1  12347 1001 battery down  TRUE
2 123455 2077 Power issue  TRUE
3 112625 7166 DG fault  TRUE
4 112621 2122 cable cut FALSE
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Only thing is df2 should be in column format. ie. df2 <- data.frame(almname = c("battery down", "Power issue", "DG fault", "Circuit break")).. Thanks. I got an idea now.

Comment: I'm getting a warning message when I try this for another data frame having different data. Also my stats mapping is wrong. It says FALSE, where ever its TRUE . Any lights on this...?  Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: can you try this: `k <- paste0(df2$almname, collapse = "|")
df1 %>% mutate(Stat = stringr::str_detect(.$almname, k))`